# UK - Testing for Tap Water

Tags: water

Water is pooling in my garden next to my neighbour's fence. He has been harassing us in multiple ways for 8 years.

It is the only place on my property where this is happening. It has never happened like this before until last year.

Last year, in the driest summer we have had in years, we saw my neighbour had a hose up to the fence which he kept on which flooded our garden. This year we can see water trickling down from his garden, but due to rain cannot be absolutely sure as we cannot see the hose. The water turns on and off, but not relating to any rain. All winter with multiple weather conditions there was no pooling. It only happens during the summer when we try and use our garden.

This water pools a few inches deep, so it is easy to take a sample.

Is there any home way of testing this water to see if it is tap water or rain water? This test has to be something that can be purchased in the UK.

If not, is there any cheap way of getting someone else to test it?

His house is a good distance from the trickling area, so it is unlikely to be a leak in his garden as there will be no piping there.

Comment: I recommend striking up an innocent conversation about water prizes with him. Probably with a hint about how lucky you are living downhill and not having to water your garden so much.

Comment: I think the question is clear: to tell by testing if water is of rain or tap origin.

Comment: I think the question was clear, but have edited it to make it even easier to understand.

Comment: Tap water is treated with chlorine so a chlorine testing kit should do the trick.